# GoogleJsonWebSignature.Payload for login should I not use Subject?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, google-signin

Using C# and NET Standard 4.7

Just like [GoogleJsonWebSignature.Payload JsonWebToken Contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878027/googlejsonwebsignature-payload-jsonwebtoken-contents) i'm working on an application using google sign in for data and i need an unique identifier to match against.
GoogleJsonWebSignature.Payload validationPayload = GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(jwt);

I get the data like this and then there is a table with an internal userId as the primary key and another row containing the validationPayload.Subject. When someone tries to login I find a user with the id number contained in subject. Now the issue I run into is that the Subject seem to be able to change over time. We have someone login with google with the email address we have stored for our internal userId but the Subject is different.

So my question is, what causes number for the subject for a user to change? I read earlier that you should not use email for authentication but perhaps I misunderstood something about that part and email is what I should match against instead of the Id? It would be interesting to know how others have solved this.

Is there any disadvantage for using a internal userId as primary key and their gmail adress to match?